# Jar file not connecting to existing database

Tags: java, sqlite, executable-jar

I have a JAR file that doesn't connect to the database even though it connects just fine in the IDE. I'm stuck and I don't know where to go from here. I am using Java 8 in IntelliJ trying to run SQLite.

Here is the code for the Database class.

```
private static Connection connection = null;
private static boolean connected = false;

static void connect() {
    String driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
    String db = "schedulerDB";
    String path = "lib\\";
    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:";

    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + path + db);
        printInfo("Connected to database : " + db);
        connected = true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        printError(1100, "Could not connect to database", e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        printError(1101, "Driver not found error", e);
    }
}
```

[image]

When I run the JAR file in the terminal, I get:

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: user)
```

Please help me.

Added `e.printStackTrace();` as requested:

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: user)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:941)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:953)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:918)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(NativeDB.java:134)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:257)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.execute(JDBC3Statement.java:52)
    at scheduler.Database.query(Database.java:337)
    at scheduler.User.buildList(User.java:42)
    at scheduler.User.<clinit>(User.java:85)
    at scheduler.Main.start(Main.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace();` to each of your `catch` blocks.  Then run your program again, edit your question, and show us the entire stack trace, including all `Caused by:` sections.

Comment: @VGR - I did that and added the result to the question, but I'm not sure it is giving me any helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of url to

```
url = "jdbc:sqlite::resource:"
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't do it right. I changed it as you said, and it didn't do anything.

Comment: What was the error it reported? Then check to ensure table `user` exist

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is actually caused by a [MalformedURLException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/MalformedURLException.html).  The reason you are getting this is because `lib\schedulerDB` is not a valid URL.

URLs *must* use forward slashes (`/`), on all systems—even Windows.  This is a requirement of [the URI specification itself](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-1.4).  (A URL is a type of URI, so every URL must conform to the rules of a URI.)

Making your URL valid should do the trick:

```
String path = "lib/";
```

Comment: Your suggestion did fix the `MalformedURLException` but I was only getting that because I added `:resource:` to the url as suggested below. Without that addition, both forward and back slash made no difference. I am still getting the original error that I was needed help with.

Comment: It would seem that your database does not have a table named `user`.  Did you define such a table?